# How to add domains to script-src directive in salesforce?

Tags: csp, content-security-policy

When creating a new trusted domain in CSP Trusted Sites (your-domain-here/lightning/setup/SecurityCspTrustedSite/home), the **script-src** directive is missing from the list. How can we add our domains to script-src?

We only have these options below:

- Allow site for connect-src
- Allow site for font-src
- Allow site for frame-src
- Allow site for img-src
- Allow site for media-src
- Allow site for style-src

Comment: I think you'll find you cannot and that Salesforce expects you to put all the script files into the Salesforce org as static resources (can be a zip of files with paths). Though I could be wrong, hence this only being a comment.

Comment: @PhilW As far as I recall, you are indeed correct.

Comment: In that case, is there a way to disable the CSP? I saw there was an option to "relax CSP" but I am unsure where this means reduce security or disable?

Comment: @PhilW sounds like a good workaround. However the script I want to inject is a dynamic script not a static script, so this Static Resource won't do either =/

Comment: I am not aware of a means to do this. I don't know if it would be possible to use an Apex REST API to service dynamically generated JavaScript and use that URL with the script loader even.